# Using Angular/CLI within VS Code, can I run Tests at same time as Builds?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've been using Angular/CLI from within the context of VS Code.

From the Terminal prompt within VS Code one can invoke `ng serve`  or `ng test` -- but is there a way to combine the two (eg: something like `ng serve test`) so that as I TDD, and develop tests first, I see the Terminal show failed tests, then go green as i write code to meet the tests, *AND* see the web page results on another screen?

Thanks!

Comment: [ng test wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test). See the poll and watch options.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions that I know of for this issue:

#### A work arround using 2 terminals

- just open 2 terminals
- in one, run `ng serve`
- in the other, run `ng test`

I tried with VS Code terminals, and traditional windows cmd terminals. It works but it is very limited and implies much visual pollution.

#### A distributable solution using an npm package

You may use an `npm` package called `npm-run-all`. This package helps you running multiple `npm` tasks in parallel or sequentially.

Just run

```
npm install --save-dev npm-run-all
```

This shall install `npm-run-all` in the dev dependencies of your project.

`npm-run-all` has 2 modes:

- `run-p`: runs multiple tasks in parallel
- `run-s`: runs multiple tasks sequentially

In the `package.json` file of your project, in the `script` section, you may now add:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "tdd": "run-p \"start\" \"test\"",
  "verify": "run-s \"test -- --watch=false\" \"lint\"",
  ...
},
```

You may call the tasks anything you want. I just named the dev task `tdd` to be more explicit on my intent.

**Note**: You may also use another `npm` package called `concurrently`, but i'm not sure it has the *run sequentially* mode.

This solution is distributable: every developper is now able to perform a `npm install` on your project and run task `tdd` (or whatever you want to call it). Moreover, you may also create task to be ran in a build factory. This alows your project to be integrated in a dev-ops context.

Answer (score 0):

npm script commands allow you to combine commands by using &&. For example, the newly generated project has a start command defined as follows:

```
 "start": "ng serve"
```

you can change it to look like this:

```
 "start": "ng test && ng serve"
```

Then start you app using

```
npm start
```

You can also define your own npm script command, e.g.

```
"serveWithTest": "ng test && ng serve"
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
npm run serveWithTest
```

By default, karma is configured to run in the watch mode, so each time you change and save your code the tests will re-run automatically.

**Update.** If the above setup doesn't work for you (as per the comment about Powershell), you can set it up differently. Add the following two commands in the scripts section in package.json:

```
"serve": "ng serve",
"preserve": "ng test"
```

Modify the property singleRun to be true in karma.conf.js.

Run both the test and serve as follows:

```
npm run serve
```

Comment: Makes sense. But I'm seeing it only get to ng test -- and no serve. Are you using VS Code or a different IDE? 
I've always wondered why VS Code "hangs" on ng serve -- not letting me enter other commands (eg: 'dir'), until I hit Ctrl-F5. Is that the expected behaviour -- or should VS Code be able to launch ng test, and come back to do other work (eg: ng serve), even chained together as you just pointed out.

Comment: I'm using VS Code and WebStorm. It works fine in VS Code. Just open the terminal using the menu View | Integrated terminal and run your commands there as you'd be running in a standalone Terminal window.

Comment: Hi Yakov. I must have something configured differently. My VSCode runs Powershell.exe -- which invokes ng -- and then won't take any more commands till I click Ctrl-C. It works....but obviously not as smoothly as what you are describing.

Comment: @user8076190 Updated my answer with another solution. See if it works in your setup.

Comment: This doesn't rerun the tests on each save (does it?). Seems of limited value.

Comment: Hi Guys, I don't see it happening for me neither. Wether in plain terminal, of in VSC terminal, I get stuck in `ng test` without being able to get into `ng serve`. I remeber it used to be possible in previous version.

Answer (score 0):

2020-02-12, win 10, VSC 1.42.0. Project has node/Express API and Angular UI, want to debug both API and UI. No, you can only debug either one, not simultaneously. 
Here is how:

### 1, open a cmd for the part you can't debug.

For example, run `ng serve` to debug node/Express. Or, `npm start` to debug Angular UI.

### 2, inside VSC's terminal, run `ng serve` if to debug Angular UI. Else skip to 3

### 3, Launch the corresponding debugger